# Changing the size of UIScreen on rotation

Tags: ios, orientation, rotation, bounds, cgrect

I am making an iPad app that starts out in the portrait orientation but can rotate over to the landscape orientation. In -(void) loadView, I call the function drawView. In drawView, I have this line of code:

```
CGRect r = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

The only problem is that it doesn't update itself when I rotate to landscape mode, so it still thinks that the screen is in the vertical orientation and if I want a text view to extend all the across the entire screen, it cuts it off at the 768th pixel, instead of the 1024th pixel. In -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate... I have         case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight: and case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:, and I would have to ideally place CGRect r = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; under each case, but I don't think that will work. Any suggestions? Thanks for your help!

Edit: I've even tried calling a function with

```
CGRect r = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

in it, but it still won't work. I place an NSLog after it and I received a response, so the app is definitely working properly and not crashing, but I am still unable to figure this out. Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem could be solved by using the `autoresizingMask` of `UIView`;

Comment: @dasdom I don't think this will work for me, as I want my code to work when the app is launched in landscape, not just when it's rotated to landscape.

Comment: @dasdom I have now. It looks as though the app rotates to landscape when it's launched. (Which I guess is what you were getting at.)

Comment: @dasdom However, this still doesn't work for me, as when I rotate my device, my view's superview doesn't appear to resize. (My view is the view of the UIViewController that is the RootViewController of the app.)

Answer (score 0):

Does your app happen to rely on plists for configuration? I've seen some apps where you can get landscape but only after you set an orientation key to false.